# Wait for all files to be deleted using FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a console app that need to monitor a specific directory and wait for all files to be deleted for a specific amount of time.
If after that time has exceeded and all of the files has not been deleted yet, I need the program to throw an exception. How can I accomplish this?

```
    public static void FileWatcher(string fileName, int timeToWatch)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        try
        {
            watcher.Path = myPath;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Filter = string.Format("*{0}*", fileName);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Task.Delay` to setup a timeout (I assume `timeToWatch` is in milliseconds, if not then change it accordingly). If the directory has no more files (not checking subfolders) then it sets the other task as completed. The method will block (`WaitAny`) until either the timeout occurs or the files are all deleted. This can easily be changed to be `async` if required.

```
public static void FileWatcher(string fileName, int timeToWatch)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    var timeout = Task.Delay(timeToWatch);
    var completedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    watcher.Path = myPath;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    watcher.Filter = string.Format("*{0}*", fileName);
    watcher.Deleted += (s, e) => OnChanged(myPath, timeout, completedTcs);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    OnChanged(myPath, timeout, completedTcs);

    // Wait for either task to complete
    var completed = Task.WaitAny(completedTcs.Task, timeout);

    // Clean up
    watcher.Dispose();

    if (completed == 1)
    {
        // Timed out            
        throw new Exception("Files not deleted in time");
    }
}

public static void OnChanged(string path, Task timeout, TaskCompletionSource<bool> completedTcs)
{
    if (!Directory.GetFiles(path).Any())
    {
        // All files deleted (not recursive)
        completedTcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
```